# How do I make sure my javascript animation runs before submit button is done?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attached code below. I have a submit button that uses a form method POST, and then it's supposed to run the javascript animation, though it kicks me to the next page before it gets the chance to run it.

Is there a way I can add a delay to the submission such that the animation is completed first? In this code, it doesn't even get a chance to run the javascript.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pt-5 text-white">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/postQuestion.css">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1>Post a question</h1>
        <br>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route("post_post") }}">
            @csrf
            {{-- Title box --}}
            <div class="none" style="margin:0 auto;">
                <input class="search" name="title" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Title" required/>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="none">
                {{-- Question box --}}
                <textarea required name="content" class="search2" type="text" id="search" placeholder='Explain your question here.

            Protip: add your code as <code> YOUR CODE HERE </code> to format correctly.'></textarea>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="dropdownTag">
                <select name="label_id" class="dropdownTag-select" required>
                    <option value="-1">Select Tag</option>
                    @foreach(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table("tags")->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get() as $tag)
                        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="container">
                <button id="button" type="submit"></button>
                <form submit="return function();">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#button").click(function () {
                $("#button").addClass("onclic", 250, validate);
            });

            function validate() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#button").removeClass("onclic");
                    $("#button").addClass("validate", 450, callback);
                }, 2250);
            }

            function callback() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#button").removeClass("validate");
                }, 1250);
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: You can call `setTimeout` or `event.preventDefault()` or a combination of both, maybe.

Comment: On the javascript code? Problem is, it wont even go to the javascript code. Just submits right away and changes page.

Comment: It appears that you have nested form elements. The general rule(which seem seem to wish to negate) is that you cannot have a form within a form - though `<form submit="return function();">` is peculiar in several ways

Comment: I might be tempted to use the `animationend` event listener to actually `submit` the form rather than try to use timeouts etc

Answer (score 1):

Using [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) you can halt the normal behavior of the form.
After that you can implement whatever you like before manually submitting the form from JS.

If what you need is to wait some time before submitting, you can then use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Then manually submit the form using [submit() function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

**Vanilla JS**

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        document.forms['test_form'].addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            form = this;
            // Make a new timeout set to go off in 1000ms (1 second)
            setTimeout(function () {
                // submit form after timeout
                form.submit();
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>

<form name="test_form" method="POST" action="{{ route('post_post') }}">
    <label for="test">Test field</label>
    <input type="input" name="test"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.forms['test_form'].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    form = this;
    // Make a new timeout set to go off in 1000ms (1 second)
    setTimeout(function() {
      // submit form after timeout
      form.submit();
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<form name="test_form" method="POST" action="{{ route('post_post') }}">
  <label for="test">Test field</label>
  <input type="input" name="test" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the "submit", then you can simply hide the submit button itself, and hang the listener on the button that will call its animations, and then, when you need it, submit.

```
...
<div class="container">
      <button id="button" type="button"></button>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" hidden />
      <form submit="return function();">
</div>
...
...
$("#button").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $("#button").addClass("onclic", 250, validate);
     ...
     $("#submit").click();
});
...
```

It is also possible without creating a hidden input through the form submission. I think this option is better.

```
...
<form id="someform" method="POST" action="{{ route("post_post") }}">
 ...
 <div class="container">
       <button id="button" type="button"></button>
       <form submit="return function();">
 </div>
...
...
 $("#button").click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#button").addClass("onclic", 250, validate);
      ...
      $("#someform").submit();
 });
...
```